# WCF : An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: wcf, linq, entity-framework-5

While testing WCF services with 150 Users, i got this exception.

Note : I am using MS Test Project for loadtesting of WCF Service. When load test is run for 100users, there is no exception.

at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)    at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)    at System.Linq.Dynamic.ClassFactory.GetDynamicClass(IEnumerable`1 properties)    at System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.CreateClass(IEnumerable`1 properties)    at System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParseNew()    at System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParseIdentifier()    at System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParsePrimaryStart()    at System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParsePrimary()    at System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParseUnary()    at System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParseMultiplicative()    at System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParseAdditive()    at System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParseComparison()    at System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParseLogicalAnd()    at System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParseLogicalOr()    at System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.ParseExpression()    at System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser.Parse(Type resultType)    at System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(ParameterExpression[] parameters, Type resultType, String expression, Object[] values)    at System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(Type itType, Type resultType, String expression, Object[] values)    at System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicQueryable.Select(IQueryable source, String selector, Object[] values)    at CustomEntities.Data.Repository.CustomEntitiesDataRepository.GetCustomEntityData(CriteriaDto criteriaDto) in d:\Projects\SRM\Services\Data\CustomEntities\CustomEntities.Data.Repository\CustomEntitiesDataRepository.cs:line 131    at CustomEntities.Data.Manager.CustomEntitiesDataManager.GetCustomEntityData(CriteriaDto criteriaDto) in d:\Projects\SRM\Services\Data\CustomEntities\CustomEntities.Data.Manager\CustomEntitiesDataManager.cs:line 69

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at your code, in `CustomEntitiesDataRepository.cs` at line 131, this line is triggering the issue.  The custom entity you are returning is, at some level, trying to insert a value into a `Dictionary<T,U>`, but the key its using already exists.

Comment: But it works fine for 100Users, mean there is no problem in repository.

Comment: @Imran No - it means you have a flaw in the logic somewhere that's not occurring regularly.  At some point, you're getting a duplicate key.  This isn't being handled.

Answer (score 2):

Actually it looks like there's a concurrency issue in `.Select()`. See http://www.webr2.com/system-linq-dynamic-select-new-does-not-appear-to-be-thread-safe/

Easiest fix is to put some locking in your code around calls to Select